# How to calculate/deal with big amounts of data?

Tags: mysql, etl, data-warehouse, bigdata

I have a table in MySQL that has about **50 million records** (continuing growing), and it is about subscription consumptions.

So, **everyday I have to select these records and make calculations** on it in order to target different kind of consumptions/clients, for example if a client is active/inactive, how long has been active, if it had changed product, and so on.

At the moment, I have different queries to select the different business cases and then I load data to the staging area and data warehouse. Although, some of **these queries are very low and they are overloading** productive environment.

I would like to know if there is a known solution(s) or technology to this kind of daily tasks.

I am open to continue with MySQl or try a new big data technology. For example, selecting everyday the millions of raw records to a staging area/ODS and then work on them with some technology.

Does anybody know good solutions for these kind of tasks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be replication - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

That way you can run whatever queries you want on the replicated DB without impacting the live DB.

Comment: Thank you @Bryan, the DB is already a slave. 
I have some queries taking 15-20 minutes, and the overall ETL process taking about 25-30 min for a day (which is a problem in case I have to load backlog/historical data). My biggest problem is that for each client I have to calculate last and penultimate consumption, and grouping data by client to then calculate every business cases is a little bit heavy. I am thinking about transporting raw data to a staging area/file and search for a technology that manipulates that data then.